# CakePHP based website becomes unresponsive in browser

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a large website built over Croogo in CakePHP. Today, without any warning, the following started to happen: if making a few consecutive HTTP request, the site remains in loading mode, inside the browser. Any attempt to access any other URL from the same domain results in the same result.

The interesting part, now: if I delete the "CAKEPHP" cookie and then try reloading it, everything works fine, until it freezes again.

Notes:

1. this is happening client side. The site is responding in other clients
2. PHP goes to use 30% of the processor power for a very short time just before the site becomes unresponsive
3. This is application related - I've tested it on three different configurations and all acted the same
4. I've commented the code I was writing before this happened and still no change
5. An Apache restart also makes the website responsive in the web browser
6. There are absolutely no slow queries. The largest time recorded for a series of queries is 134 ms. Also PHP mostly only parses data, with no demanding operations
7. This is happening equally in scripts with only one query and one variable showing and scripts that are parsing large data sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by telling CakePHP to store sessions into database instead of "php".